# integrating google minify with zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, action, minify

so I tried to integrate minify and zend framework

http://code.google.com/p/minify/

what I basically did was copy the contents of minify's index.php file to a zend action:

and changed the third line from

```
define('MINIFY_MIN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
```

to

```
define('MINIFY_MIN_DIR', 'Z:\wamp2\www\min');
```

which is where the minify folder is located

here's the full action:

```
  public function test2Action()
    {
      define('MINIFY_MIN_DIR', 'Z:\wamp2\www\min');
       // load config
      require MINIFY_MIN_DIR . '/config.php';

      // setup include path
      set_include_path($min_libPath . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

      require 'Minify.php';

      Minify::$uploaderHoursBehind = $min_uploaderHoursBehind;
      Minify::setCache(
          isset($min_cachePath) ? $min_cachePath : ''
          ,$min_cacheFileLocking
      );

      if ($min_documentRoot) {
          $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = $min_documentRoot;
      } elseif (0 === stripos(PHP_OS, 'win')) {
          Minify::setDocRoot(); // IIS may need help
      }

      $min_serveOptions['minifierOptions']['text/css']['symlinks'] = $min_symlinks;

      if ($min_allowDebugFlag && isset($_GET['debug'])) {
          $min_serveOptions['debug'] = true;
      }

      if ($min_errorLogger) {
          require_once 'Minify/Logger.php';
          if (true === $min_errorLogger) {
              require_once 'FirePHP.php';
              Minify_Logger::setLogger(FirePHP::getInstance(true));
          } else {
              Minify_Logger::setLogger($min_errorLogger);
          }
      }

      // check for URI versioning
      if (preg_match('/&\\d/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
          $min_serveOptions['maxAge'] = 31536000;
      }
      if (isset($_GET['g'])) {
          // well need groups config
          $min_serveOptions['minApp']['groups'] = (require MINIFY_MIN_DIR . '/groupsConfig.php');
      }
      if (isset($_GET['f']) || isset($_GET['g'])) {
          // serve!
         Minify::serve('MinApp', $min_serveOptions);
         //echo Minify::combine(array('//css/DisplayHelpers/DisplayObject.css'),$min_serveOptions);

      } else{
         echo 'fail';
      }

        // action body
    }
```

notice these lines...I added the combine line which is commented out

```
 Minify::serve('MinApp', $min_serveOptions);
 //echo Minify::combine(array('//css/DisplayHelpers/DisplayObject.css'),$min_serveOptions);
```

the 
 `Minify::serve('MinApp', $min_serveOptions);` line is in the original index.php....if I keep it there, it will not return the correct minifed files properly and instead return some crazy gibberish when I go to `http://localhost/tester/test2?f=/css/DisplayHelpers/DisplayObject.css`...

on the other hand, when I go to `http://localhost/min?f=/css/DisplayHelpers/DisplayObject.css` which uses minify's index.php it would work properly

on the other hand if I uncomment the combine line and comment the serve line it would also work properly but it won't do caching, etc

any ideas on how to resolve in using the normal serve method within the zend action so that I can use the cache?

Comment: Why an action plus there's already a Zend helper in that project.

Comment: @Adrian World Add as answer. Also link to https://github.com/bubba-h57/zf-helpers . Why all these stuffs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why an action plus there's already a [Zend helper](https://github.com/bubba-h57/zf-helpers) in that project.